# Unable to Configure php.ini with VestaCP

Tags: php, apache, debian

I'm running VestaCP on Debian-Stable and am trying to configure my PHP.

Via phpinfo, I can verify that the location of php.ini that's being read is /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini, but it seems no matter what I do, the server is not reading any of my changes.

For example, whether I set display_errors to On or Off, I don't see any of the main errors on my index.php site.  I just see "Notice: Undefined index: multi in /[file] on line 67" which I understand is some sort of odd bug in PHP 5 to begin with.

I've tried setting error_reporting = E_ALL, as well as ~E_ALL, I still see only that notice and nothing else.

Interestingly, though, when I tried a solution from another Stack Overflow thread - I pasted this at the start of the file, under [PHP]:

```
<?php
// Turn off all error reporting
error_reporting(0);
?>
```

THIS caused all sorts of stuff to show up, such as:

```
Warning: session_start(): Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /[path]/index.php:15) in /[path]/public_html/top.php on line 2
```

But I still get that stupid notice.

What's going on? How come if I set display errors to On or Off it isn't actually doing what it should?

Comment: The notice is probably because of the php code. You're calling for a value of an array but the key you're calling it with doesn't exists. An example: `$a=array('foo'=>'bar');$a['not_found'];` the only working key for array `$a` is: `$a['foo'];`

Comment: Well yeah, I get that - but I'm more interested in hiding the notice. It's not an actual error, it's just being annoying.

Comment: Then I would like to suggest you to have a better look at function [`error_reporting`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php). Of course you put this at the top of your file. Not at the bottom.

Comment: I put it where it was originally, just uncommented it.

Comment: Yeah, I just tried cutting and pasting it so the top of the file reads: `[PHP]
display_errors = Off
error_reporting = ~E_ALL

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
; About php.ini   ;`

That didn't help either. I still see the same notification.